# Excel: how to match two columns from two sheets with condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets; let's call S1 and S2

S1 looks like this

```
ID.  Citizen
0.   U.S.
1.   Canandian
2.   U.S.
3.   Canadian
4.   Canadian
```

S2 looks like this

```
ID. 
0. 
2.  
4.
```

So S2 has some missing IDs

Now; what I want to do is that

(1) adding one more column in S2 called "Canadian"

```
ID.  Canadian
```

(2) Then, I look the IDs in S1 that also appeared in S2; and check its corresponding citizen in S1; if Canadian; then in S2 second column, I put True; else False

So S2 should look like this

```
ID. Canadian
0.   False
2.   False
4.   True
```

Is there any general formula ? Thanks

Comment: Your mock up has "Canada", not "Canadian", your result has "Canada", not "True". What do you really want? In any case, this can easily be done with Vlookup.

Comment: @teylyn thanks for point out; I've fixed the typo; I'm very new to excel; so if its possible for you to explain the Vlookup with the formula ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming on S2 the first row is the labels, then the formula in B2 would be as follows.

To return the country from S1:

```
=Vlookup(A2,S1!$A$1:$B$100,2,false)
```

To return TRUE if the country is "Canada", compare the result with the text "Canada"

```
=Vlookup(A2,S1!$A$1:$B$100,2,false)="Canada"
```

Copy the formula down.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer; I'm wondering what's the 100 there stands for? the total number of rows in the sheet ?

Comment: just a follow up; what is in my `S2`; I don't want to use boolean `True` or `False` but instead want to use string like `Canadian` and `U.S.` ?

Comment: The formula looks at cells A1 to B100. Change it to the rows you need. In your question you say you want to return true or false. In my answer I have shown you first how to return the country, then how to return true or false. Which part is giving you trouble?